# jQuery Selector Submenu / Dropdown

Tags: jquery, list, drop-down-menu, this, submenu

I'd like to build a very simple submenu:

HTML:

```
<ul>
  <li><a href="#">Main-item</a>
     <ul id="show">
        <li id="subitem"><a href="#">Sub-Item</a></li>
     </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#access').hover(function () {
    $(this).find('ul').stop().animate({opacity:1, paddingTop:'10px'}, 400);
  }, function () {
    $(this).find('ul').stop().animate({opacity:0, paddingTop:'0px'}, 300);
  });
});
```

**ul** has a background image and I want the #show should be animate or not just all li

Comment: Now just the li moving an not the ul (#show), I´d some issues with the right selector. http://jsfiddle.net/ZLEQ4/ The grey div doesen´t move with the li.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can only imagine what you want to do.

#### Check out the sample and this [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wv5Zs/1/)

#### Sample

**Html**

```
<div id="access">
<ul>
  <li><a href="#">Main-item</a>
     <ul id="show">
        <li id="subitem"><a href="#">Sub-Item</a></li>
     </ul>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#">Main-item 2</a>
     <ul id="show">
        <li id="subitem"><a href="#">Sub-Item</a></li>
     </ul>
  </li>    
</ul>
</div>
```

**jQuery**

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    $('li[id!="show"]').hover(function () {
        $(this).find('ul#show').stop().animate({opacity:1, paddingTop:'10px'}, 400);
    }, function () {
        $(this).find('ul#show').stop().animate({opacity:0, paddingTop:'0px'}, 300);
    })
});
```

Comment: Thanks, my english is´t the best. It should look likes this: `http://www.tuttoaster.com/wp-content/uploads/demos/3/navigation.html`

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, you need a simple change: `$('#access')` should be `$('#access > ul > li')` (assuming `#access` is the parent of the top `ul`).

Then the hover functions will apply to the `li`, finding its single submenu `ul`, whereas currently, you're finding all of the submenus.

Comment: I think it should've worked for you (I did it: http://jsfiddle.net/wv5Zs/7/). Anyway, you should avoid using the same id on more than one element.